# Shapefile to PostGIS to GeoJSON - co-ordinates

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, geojson

I'm trying to do what must be a very basic and common operation:
load a Shapefile into PostGIS, and then search within a bounding box,
returning GeoJSON.

Putting the Shapefile in like this, specifying with `-s` the SRID that will be used
in the DB:

```
shp2pgsql  -s 4326 -I "$SHP" public.dmz2 | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres
```

Since my SQL is giving weird results, I have put aside the bounding box and
am just trying to get everything back as GeoJSON:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) from dmz2;
```

Some kind of JSON is returned, but it has co-ordinates with huge numbers such as:

```
[304683.762700001, 530184.6255]
```

I was expecting latitude/longitude...is that wrong?

Comment: What is the crs of the original data? If it is not lon, lat then do not tell postgis it is using -s

Comment: I thought `-s` would convert that, but I see I only supplied one value, not the two required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ian Turton for his comment that drew my attention to the fact that I thought `shp2psql`'s `-s` argument meant the Shapefile's co-ordinate system was being converted -- I had only supplied one value, not the two required. The correct argument in my case was `-s 27700:4326`.